# Display block after fadeout or fadein after fadeto

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadeout

When I click on an image I want a div to fadein and then fadeout. This div should always occupy the same space (`display: block`).
If I click again, I want this div to reappear.

Can't achieve this. If I use `fadeOut()`, an inline style `display:none` is added. If I use `fadeTo()`, the div is hidden without occupying its space.

How do I have to do it?

Code:

```js
function edit(oneid)
{
  AvisEdit(oneid);
  }

function AvisEdit(oneid)
{
 var nom = $('#X'+oneid+' .Nom').text();
 ShowAlerts("Ara pots editar el valor dels camps de '"+nom+"'", 2);
}


function ShowAlerts(sms, code)
{
 switch(code)
 {
  case 0:
   Actions(sms, "success");
   break;
  
  case 1:
   Actions(sms, "error");
   break;
  case 2:
   Actions(sms, "info");
   break;
 }
}

function Actions(sms, tipus)
{
 $("#warningboxes").toggleClass(tipus); // Add class
 $('#warningboxes').css('visibility','visible').hide();  // start hidden to fadein
 $("#warningboxes").html(sms); // add message in div
 $("#warningboxes").fadeIn(1500, function() // show up
  {
   setTimeout(function()
   {
    $('#warningboxes').fadeOut(1500, 0); // dissapears but removes space of div #warningboxes; with fadeto(), fadein won't work anymore
   }, 1500)
   
   
   setTimeout(function()
   {
    BackToStd(tipus);  // remove the properties added so it still works
    
   }, 3000);
  }   
 );
}

function BackToStd(tipus)
{
 $('#warningboxes').toggleClass(tipus);
 $('#warningboxes').css(
  {
   display: "block",
   opacity: "",
   filter: "",
   zoom: "",
   visibility: ""
  }
 );
}
```

```css
.warningboxes
{
 border: 1px solid;
 margin: 10px 0px;
 padding:15px 10px 15px 50px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 10px center;
 visibility:hidden;
 display:block;
}
.info 
{
 color: #00529B;
 background-color: #BDE5F8;
 background-image: url('../res/PNGICONS/KnobInfo.png');
}
.success 
{
 color: #4F8A10;
 background-color: #DFF2BF;
 background-image: url('../res/PNGICONS/KnobValidGreen.png');
}
.warning 
{
 color: #9F6000;
 background-color: #FEEFB3;
 background-image: url('../res/PNGICONS/KnobAttention.png');
}
.error 
{
 color: #D8000C;
 background-color: #FFBABA;
 background-image: url('../res/PNGICONS/KnobCancel.png');
}
```

```html
<body>

 <div class="warningboxes" id ="warningboxes" name="warningboxes"> Info message</div>
 <table id="myid">
      ....
      ....
      ...
      
      <img src='./res/edit.png' id='imagenok4' class='deleteAndOthers' OnClick='edit(4)'>
      <img src='./res/edit.png' id='imagenok5' class='deleteAndOthers' OnClick='edit(5)'>
      <img src='./res/edit.png' id='imagenok6' class='deleteAndOthers' OnClick='edit(6)'>
      ....
```

Adding all the code would be too messy and irrelevant. The important part is in

```
function Actions(sms, tipus)
```

as here is where I fadein and fadeout...

I have read lots about this but can't make my code to work.

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code. On first click on the `img`, the `div` fades out. On clicking again, it fades back in.

**Update:** Now if you want the div to be faded out initially, you just need to add the class `gone` manually at the start. Because that is the class that causes the `div` to have zero `opacity`.

```js
$("#fade-img").on("click", function(e){
  $("#fade-div").toggleClass("gone");
});//img click
```

```css
#fade-div
{
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
  width: 200px;
}

#fade-div.gone
{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="fade-img" src="http://placehold.it/100X100" alt="" />
<div id="fade-div" class="gone"></div>
```

Comment: Looks good but can't sort it out yet... How do you do the same but starting hidden and then making it visible? Instead of visible->hidden->visible? Thanks. Mmm wait I think I have it, gotta do some more tests. Just seen your answer (that you are giong to update). Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, very useful!

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my phone, so unable to provide a code example, but try animating the opacity with CSS by adding/removing a class.